# Recommended workspace layout with Bazaar

Tags: layout, bazaar, workspace

I am trying to setup directory structure (workspace layout), I need to separate "stable" and "dev" code, and have several releases. I found this [Recommended Mercurial repository/folder structure for an SVN user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367453/recommended-mercurial-repository-folder-structure-for-an-svn-user/2369272#2369272)
Is this possible under Bazaar vcs? Any other suggestion to correctly structure directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work fine with Bazaar. eg.:

```
my-project (Bazaar shared repository[1])
+ trunk (you can use this for dev if you like)
+ branches (normal directory)
  + v1 (branch for a specific version)
  + v2 
+ stable (push the stable stuff in here)
```

You can use whatever directory structure that you like, but using the svn layout helps to make things consistent for others on your project that have worked with svn.

With Bazaar like with Mercurial you don't really need branches
for each release because if you release off of trunk or stable 
then you can just tag it which basically sets a pointer to the revision. Although it is handy to keep a branch per series onto which you can push minor bug fixes to be released as part of the next bugfix release for that series.

[1] Make the base directory for your project a Bazaar shared repository, so that each branch does not keep a copy of the revision history but in stead store all the history in the repository. You can create a Bazaar repository with `bzr init-repo /path/to/my-project` which will create the directory for you too. All branches pushed or branched under that directory will automatically use the shared repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can also read the official Bazaar documentation on [organizing branches](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.4/en/user-guide/organizing_branches.html) and [advanced shared repository layouts](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.4/en/user-guide/shared_repository_layouts.html).